# submitting a form on change Jquery

Tags: jquery, forms, post, submit

I am trying to programmatically submit this form that is in an `iframe` so i can add an image to a database...

code:

```
var item_id = $("#itemid").text();
  var link = $("#mainIMG").attr("src");
   $('#curItem').append('<iframe border="none" width="600px" height="600px" id="uploadIframe"></iframe>')
  $('#uploadIframe').contents().find('body').append('<form name="addImgForm" enctype="multipart/form-data" id="addImgForm" action="addImageForm.php" method="POST"></form>');
  $('#uploadIframe').contents().find('#addImgForm').append('<input id="newIMG" type="file" name="file">')
  .append('<input name="item_id" value="'+item_id+'" type="text"/>')
  .append('<input name="link" type="text" value="'+link+'"/>')
  .append('<input id="IframeSub" type="submit"/>');
  $('#uploadIframe').contents().find('body').append('<script type="text/javascript" src="../JS/editItem.js"></script>');
  $('#uploadIframe').contents().find("#newIMG").trigger('click');
  $('#uploadIframe').contents().find("#newIMG").change(function (){
    $('#uploadIframe').contents().find('#addImgForm [name=addImgForm]').submit();
});
```

What I have tried by far:

1. inserting the script that submits the form into the head of the iframe.
2. referencing this same file with a function that will submit it.

Comment: Is that all your code? If it is, you need to close your anonymous function that's inside your `change()` method.

Comment: @ZakAngelle no im sorry i left that out ill edit it

Comment: Do you get your iframe filled with all you are appending?

Comment: @Jai yes i do, everything works perfectly. i just cant get it to submit..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alright.. what seemed to make the difference is `[name=addItemForm]`. The funny thing is... when i was working on this same thing at work, this did not work. i had to submit the form like i did previously with

`$('#uploadIframe').contents().find('#addImgForm [name=addImgForm]').submit();`

oddly enough it didnt work. this is what works.... for now... :)

```
  var item_id = $("#itemid").text();
  var link = $("#mainIMG").attr("src");

  $('#curItem').append('<iframe border="none" width="600px" height="600px" id="uploadIframe"></iframe>')
  $('#uploadIframe').contents().find('body').append('<form name="addImgForm" enctype="multipart/form-data" id="addImgForm" action="addImageForm.php" method="POST"></form>');
  $('#uploadIframe').contents().find('#addImgForm').append('<input id="newIMG" type="file" name="file">')
  .append('<input name="item_id" value="'+item_id+'" type="text"/>')
  .append('<input name="link" type="text" value="'+link+'"/>')
  .append('<input id="IframeSub" type="submit"/>');
  $('#uploadIframe').contents().find("#newIMG").trigger('click');
  $('#uploadIframe').contents().find('body').append('<script type="text/javascript" src="../JS/editItem.js"></script>');

  $('#uploadIframe').contents().find('#newIMG').change(function (){
    $('#uploadIframe').contents().find("#addImgForm").submit();
  });
```